# Scrapy parsing JSON output

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl a website. Some pages use AJAX so I got the AJAX requests to get the actual data. so far so good. The output of those AJAX requests is JSON outputs. Now I would like to parse the JSON but Scrapy just provides HtmlXPathSelector. Has anybody transformed successfully a JSON output into HTML and been able to parse it with HtmlXPathSelector?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You do not want to convert JSON to HTML.  Can you give us a sample of the JSON response.

Answer (score 5):

```
import json

response = json.loads(jsonResponse)
```

The code above will decode the json you receive. Afterwards, you should be able to process it any way you want.

(Replace `jsonResponse` with the json that you get from the ajax request)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly complicated, still works.

If you're interested in working with xpaths on JSON outputs..

Disclaimer : May not be the optimal soln. +1 if someone improves this approach.

install dicttoxml package (pip recommended)

-Download the output using scrapy's traditional Request module

in spider:

```
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
import lxml.etree as etree

request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_resp)
yield request

def parse_resp(self,response):
     json=response.body
     #Now load the contents using python's JSON module
     json_dict = json.loads(json)
     #transform the contents into xml using dicttoxml
     xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(json_dict)
     xml = etree.fromstring(xml)
     #Apply scrapy's XmlXPathSelector module,and start using xpaths
     xml = XmlXPathSelector(text=xml)
     data = xml.select(".//*[@id='count']/text()").extract()
     return data
```

I did this because, i'm maintaining all the xpaths of all the spiders in one place (config-files)